# For loop issue to get output

Tags: shell-script, for

```
for a in {P02183606,P02183608,sassa}
do
    for b in {PID,PID2,sas}
    do
        echo "http://indiafirstlife.com//onlineInsurance-rest/uploadDocument/uploadDocumentsOmniMannualPush?applicationRefNo=$a&applicationFormId=$b"
    done
done
```

Expected output

```
http://indiafirstlife.com//onlineInsurance-rest/uploadDocument/uploadDocumentsOmniMannualPush?applicationRefNo=P02183606&applicationFormId=PID
http://indiafirstlife.com//onlineInsurance-rest/uploadDocument/uploadDocumentsOmniMannualPush?applicationRefNo=P02183608&applicationFormId=PID2
http://indiafirstlife.com//onlineInsurance-rest/uploadDocument/uploadDocumentsOmniMannualPush?applicationRefNo=sassa&applicationFormId=sas
```

Comment: Please edit your question and use the formatting options provided. Also, you're not asking a question. What output do you expect? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would recommend running shell scripts through [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) to guard against syntax errors and the like. Your two lists to iterate over are not well-formed.

Comment: You get 3x3 output... because you have nested loop ... it is difficult to tell hwo you want to achieve what you want to achieve. Where is your input coming from?

Comment: -Plumo Your right what will be solution for expected outup

Answer (score 1):

You want to *pair up* the two lists that you have rather than combine them in every possible combination.

One way to do that:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -- P02183606 P02183608 sassa

for formid in PID PID2 sas; do
    printf '...urlpath...?applicationRefNo=%s&applicationFormId=%s\n' "$1" "$formid"
    shift
done
```

This sets the positional parameters to the list of reference numbers, and then loops over the form IDs.  In each iteration, the URL is printed with these inserted using `printf`, and the `shift` at the end of the loop shifts the first positional parameter off that list.

Note that using a brace expansion is not needed just to represent a simple list.

Comment: Thnk u very much however it seem there is liitle change need to do see the out i got   

...urlpath...?applicationRefNo=P02183606,P02183608,sassa&applicationFormId=PID
...urlpath...?applicationRefNo=&applicationFormId=PID2
...urlpath...?applicationRefNo=&applicationFormId=sas


applicationRefNo value not getting

Comment: @Santosh Read my answer again. I have no commas in the lists I use.

Comment: its working with printf i need to use curl command instead of printf please help thanks in advance

Comment: @Santosh Your question ask about how to modify your code to get a very particular output (well, this is what we inferred, there is actually no real question in the text). This is what me and pLumo has shown. If you had wanted to use `curl` for anything, you should have said so in the question.

Comment: exactly. thanks Kusa ;-) and sorry for me shouting, couldn't resist ^^

Answer (score 1):

Using arrays:

```
a=(P02183606 P02183608 sassa)
b=(PID PID2 sas)

for i in "${!a[@]}"; do
    printf 'http://...?applicationRefNo=%s&applicationFormId=%s\n' "${a[$i]}" "${b[$i]}"
done
```

---

Alternative, simple `printf`:

```
arr=(P02183606 PID P02183608 PID2 sassa sas)

printf 'http://...?applicationRefNo=%s&applicationFormId=%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

or even without array:

```
printf 'http://...?applicationRefNo=%s&applicationFormId=%s\n' P02183606 PID P02183608 PID2 sassa sas
```

Comment: Thank u very much yaar

Comment: Hi Sir Your solution is working for however its not working at in curl
a=(P02183606 P02183608 sassa)
b=(PID PID2 sas)
for i in "${!a[@]}"; do
curl -i -H "Authorization:Token eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJlVGVybVVzZXIiLCJwYXNzd29yZCI6IkZ1bGNydW0jMSIsInJvbGUiOiJCRE0iLCJleHAiOjE1ODg2MDY1NDd9.P-_JwXRcPtEky3wbKbQ-fTGIkxYPw_OCWRvlcFybYSd3IWAtzrHWK8OHK4WRvkU2rDgGt5HeTSpxJya3oxyxow" "Content-type: application/json" -X GET ' 
 http://indiafirstlife.com//onlineInsurance-rest/uploadDocument/uploadDocumentsOmniMannualPush?applicationRefNo=%s&applicationFormId=%s\n' "${a[$i]}" "${b[$i]}"
done

Comment: This depends on `printf`, you cannot do the same with `curl`. You said in your Q you want output, and now you want to run directly in `curl` ??

Comment: Sorry for that however for practice purpose i was checking the same if parameter coming  in service or not could you help with curl |

Comment: Read this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865866/pipe-output-of-cat-to-curl-to-download-a-list-of-files